# making a df based on rows from another df when multiple conditions are true

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to create a new df using another one when multiple conditions are met.
As in - I have a df with pressure and depth data that I want to split into three smaller df.

```
a shallow one < 2900m 
the mid range > 2901m but <3500m
and deep >3501m
```

I've tried cod that looks like this:

```
mid =df[df.depth > 2958 & < 3530]
```

for the middle one and get an invalid syntax.

if there is only one condition I can do it with:

```
shallow = df[df.depth < 2900]
```

and it works just fine, I'm jut not sure how to put multiple conditions in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For multiple conditions you can join them together with `&` logic. Also you should use the *or equals* such that your conditions don't have a gap between [2900, 2901], for instance.

#### Sample data

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'depth': np.linspace(2700, 3900, 13)})
```

#### Code

```
df[(df['depth'] >= 2900) & (df['depth'] < 3500)]
#    depth
#2  2900.0
#3  3000.0
#4  3100.0
#5  3200.0
#6  3300.0
#7  3400.0

#Equivalently with the `.lt`, `.gt`, `.le`, `.ge`, `.ne`, `.eq` operators
df[df['depth'].ge(2900) & df['depth'].lt(3500)]
```

This requires you to define a variable number of variables if you want to store each sub-DataFrame. Instead of doing that you can use `pd.cut` together with a groupby to store the results in a `dict` if you want (or just act on the `groupby` object).

```
d = dict(tuple(df.groupby(pd.cut(df['depth'], [-np.inf, 2900, 3500, np.inf], 
                                 right=False, labels=['shallow', 'mid', 'deep']))))

d['shallow']
#    depth
#0  2700.0
#1  2800.0

d['mid']
#    depth
#2  2900.0
#3  3000.0
#4  3100.0
#5  3200.0
#6  3300.0
#7  3400.0

d['deep']
#     depth
#8   3500.0
#9   3600.0
#10  3700.0
#11  3800.0
#12  3900.0
```